# Can I use the keyrock GE inside my android app?

Tags: fiware

Is there a way to incorporate the Identity Management GE into my android app that I am developing? and if so, what tutorials should I follow to go about this?

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it is not necessary to have installed the Identity Management GE into your android app, just call the global instance that it is created in the FIWARE Lab. Take a look to the presentation [Adding Identity Management and Access Control to your Application](http://www.slideshare.net/flopezaguilar/idm-and-ac) for more details of the different operations that you should follow to provide authentication to your application.

Comment: So you are saying that I should have a running instance of KeyRock and have the android app call it? 
how will I make the request from the android?

Comment: Take a look into the presentation that I provide in my answer. Just make a REST request to the instance in order to authenticate your application. Keep in mind that you need to register the application firstly in the Keyrock instance.